# Run local command from expect script

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I am trying to kill a local background process at a certain point in an `expect` script.
Consider the sample script:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect
set killPID [lindex $argv 0];
set timeout 1
spawn ftp ftp.ftp.com
expect "Name"
send "Username\r"
expect "Password:"
send "xxxxxx\r"
expect "ftp>"
send_user "Killing local process id: $killPID\n"
interact
```

I run this script with the id of a local process that I want to kill as first argument.
How can I kill the process just before the `interact` command?

Comment: You can first kill the process in the script and then perform expect. That looks easy, if you don't have tight requirements.

Comment: @vishram0709 Thanks, but this is just a sample to illustrate. The actual script is more complicated. So I need to kill it inside the expect script. In general, I am asking how to execute a local command (like `kill $killPID`) from within an expect script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a command on the local machine that requires no interaction, do:

```
exec kill $killPID
```

Comment: Things get much more complex if you want to do things remotely or if you want to interact with two subprocesses at once. You definitely _can_ but it isn't as simple by far.