# Bash script with expect that executes commands locally and in sftp

Tags: bash, sftp, expect

I need to do an sftp login in a shell script with bash. I have seen some examples here with `expect`. The problem is that I need to insert a password that is read from the input of the user, that is, I need something like

```
echo "Insert password: "
read my_passwd
```

and then I would send the `my_passwd`. So I would like an script like

```
echo "Insert password: "
read my_passwd

spawn sftp usr@example.com
expect "password: "
send "$my_passwd\n"

expect "sftp>"
send "get mbr*"

expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
```

but `echo` and `read` don't run. Even with this solution of adding `exec` (`exec read my_passwd`) before I still get an error ([Run local command from expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911026/run-local-command-from-expect-script))

Comment: `echo` and `read` are shell script commands, not `expect` commands.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: See an simple example: [sftp-with-sexpect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brp0M.png)